# Deform a triangle along vector to get a specific angle

Tags: math, 3d, geometry

I am trying to create a binary tree from a lot of segments in 3d space sharing the same origin.
When merging two segments I want to have a specific angle between the lines to the child nodes.
The following image illustrates my problem. C shows the position of the parent node and A and B the child positions. N is the average vector of the vectors from C to A and C to B.

[image: triangle]

With a given angle, how can I determine point P?
Thanks for any help

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood the question, Do you mean that the inputs are the points A,B,C, the vector N and the angle?

Comment: Yes, that's right. A, B and C are given. N can be calculated from AC and AB and what I want is the Position P for the given angle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
P = C + t * ((A + B)/2 - C)    t is unknown parameter
PA = A - P                     PA vector 
PB = B - P                     PB vector
Tan(Fi) = (PA x PB) / (PA * PB)    (cross product in the nominator, scalar product in the denominator)
Tan(Fi) * (PA.x*PB.x + PA.y*PB.y) = (PA.x*PB.y - PA.y*PB.x)
```

this is quadratic equation for t, after solving we will get two (for non-degenerate cases) possible positions of P point (the second one lies at other side of AB line)

**Addition:**

```
Let's ax = A.x  - A point X-coordinate and so on,
abcx = (ax+bx)/2-cx, abcy = (ay+by)/2-cy
pax = ax-cx - t*abcx, pay = ay-cy - t*abcy
pbx = bx-cx - t*abcx, pby = by-cy - t*abcy
ff = Tan(Fi) , then
ff*(pax*pbx+pay*pby)-pax*pby+pay*pbx=0
ff*((ax-cx - t*abcx)*(bx-cx - t*abcx)+(ay-cy - t*abcy)*(by-cy - t*abcy)) -
 - (ax-cx - t*abcx)*(by-cy - t*abcy) + (ay-cy - t*abcy)*(bx-cx - t*abcx) = 

 t^2 *(ff*(abcx^2+abcy^2)) + 
 t *  (-2*ff*(abcx^2+abcy^2) + abcx*(by-ay) + abcy*(ax-bx) ) +
      (ff*((ax-cx)*(bx-cx)+(ay-cy)*(by-cy)) - (ax-cx)*(by-cy)+(bx-cx)*(ay-cy)) =0
```

This is quadratic equation `AA*t^2 + BB*t + CC = 0`  with coefficients

```
AA = ff*(abcx^2+abcy^2)
BB = -2*ff*(abcx^2+abcy^2) + abcx*(by-ay) + abcy*(ax-bx)
CC = ff*((ax-cx)*(bx-cx)+(ay-cy)*(by-cy)) - (ax-cx)*(by-cy)+(bx-cx)*(ay-cy)
```

**P.S.** My answer is for 2d-case!

For 3d: It is probably simpler to use scalar product only (with vector lengths)

```
Cos(Fi) = (PA * PB) / (|PA| * |PB|)
```

Comment: Isn't PA x PB = mod(PA)*mod(PB)*sin(theta) ?

Comment: @Abhishek Bansal Yes, it is. But we don't want to calculate vector lengths (with square roots), so use both scalar and cross product to eliminate (reduce) mod's

Comment: Got it! Didn't know mod of cross product is also PA.x*PB.y - PA.y*PB.x

Comment: Thanks for the promising answer. I will try it tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: Ah, Tg(Fi) reminded me of old times back in Russia... Everybody else uses "tan" instead of "tg".

Comment: I think 2D is also fine for my case and makes it less complex. I'm trying for hours now to solve this equation to get a formula that I can implement right away. But my math skills seem have become rusty. I have written a full page with the outfactored components and failed to merge them. Maybe you can give me a approach how to solve it?

Comment: @Satara Added some calculations

Comment: Awesome. Thank you! So to implement this I would just divide BB and CC through AA (to remove the AA in front of t^2) and use the  pq-formula, right? But first of all I will have to compute the 2d points :)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution could be using **binary search** on the vector **N**, whether **P** is close to **C** then the angle will be smaller and whether **P** is far from **C** then the angle will be bigger, being it suitable for a binary search.

Comment: How can I perform a binary search on a vector? Do you mean computing and checking the angle in descrete steps along N until the desired angle is reached? I think this would be too slow for my case because it have to be done in real-time.

Comment: yes, you have to assume the point P, then calculate the angle, if the angle is greater than the desired angle then go to the left(close to the point C) otherwise go to the right (far from C), and yes it will be more slow than the other approach but not too slow, because is still a log complexity.