# Moving vertex along bisector to set a specific angle

Tags: math, graphics, geometry, trigonometry, computational-geometry

I've got a three nodes A, B, C which create an angle α.

**Question:** how to find a position of B' (x,y coordinates) which is effectively a shift of B along α bisector, that AB'C angle is equal to α+5°

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here (with bisector) simpler solution is possible.

Angle BCB' is 2.5 degrees

Side BB' of triangle BCB' might be calculated using Law of Sines as

```
Len(BB') = Len(BC) *  sin(2.5) / sin(alpha/2+2.5)
```

Unit bisector vector

```
bis = BC/Len(BC) + BA/Len(BA)
bis = bis / Len(bis)
```

B' coordinates

```
B' = B + bis * Len(BB')
```

Comment: Thank you @MBo, your original solution works beautifully, but I will give a go with your simplified version.

Answer (score 1):

I've actually just found the answer to the same problem (from the mathematical point of view), just described slightly differently:
[Deform a triangle along vector to get a specific angle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18874339/deform-a-triangle-along-vector-to-get-a-specific-angle?rq=1)